# Error when installing expo-cli --global on windows 10

Tags: node.js, expo

I tried installing the expo CLI on Windows 10 and it failed with the following error.

```
C:\projectreact>npm install expo-cli --global
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-cli failed, reason: connect EACCES 104.16.26.35:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:223:5)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-cli failed, reason: connect EACCES 104.16.26.35:443
```

For some reason, this installation worked on Windows 7.

Comment: What have you tried so far to actually solve the problem? What research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching off your firewall and anti-virus. Had same issue and this worked for me.